# Postgresql 8.4 Tuning Guide

Tags: postgresql

I'm struggling to find some useful guides which point me in the right direction. I have a small database (~100MB, the biggest table has 800k records), but data fetching based on several combined joins seems very slow, although the statements look fine in EXPLAIN (mainly index usage, partly Seq Scan).

Please let me know which guides you found useful.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote [a guide to tuning PostgreSQL performance](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/Tuning_PostgreSQL_on_your_Dedicated_Server) a while ago, that should apply to 8.4 just as well as it does to the older versions we support.